# BOTO3 DynamoDB error: delete an item from a LIST attribute in a dynamodb table

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

we have a dynamoDB table with 'item_id' as primary/hash key. One of the attributes 'my_list' is a list of strings. I am trying to remove index '0' from the list. When I hard code the index, it works:

```
item_key = {'item_id': {'S': item_id}}
update_expression = "remove mylist[0]"

response = client.update_item(
    TableName=table_name, Key=item_key, UpdateExpression=update_expression)
```

BUT when I try to pass the index as a variable, I get an error:

```
item_key = {'item_id': {'S': item_id}}
update_expression = "remove mylist[:n]"

update_expression_values = {':n': {'N': 0}}

response = client.update_item(
    TableName=table_name, Key=item_key, UpdateExpression=update_expression,
    ExpressionAttributeValues=update_expression_values)
```

botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeValues.:n.N, value: 0, type: , valid types: class 'str'

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, simply pass the zero as a string:

`update_expression_values = {':n': {'N': '0'}}`

That should fix it